# Last command in ksh

Tags: command-history, ksh

In bash I can use `!!` to indicate the last command. In ksh I think you can use `r` to do something similar, but it seems to fail in one of my common patterns: typing `sudo [last command]`.

```
> cp foo /bar
cp: permission denied
> r c       # If I do this it will repeat my cp call
> sudo r c  # when I do this, it tells me that "r" is not a command
```

How can I use history to quickly type "sudo [last command]"?

Answer (score 2):

I would use command line edition: type <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Home</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, or some other sequence in vi mode), then enter `sudo␣` and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

[mksh](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) ships this default alias in its example `.mkshrc` file since some time already:

```
alias doch='sudo mksh -c "$(fc -ln -1)"'
```

Here, “doch” is a pun only German speakers may understand, so let me attempt to explain: some command tells you you aren’t allowed to do something, which leads to a yes-no-yes-no situation, except we have a specific word for this in German. So, this alias is a response “nee-nee, I *am* allowed to do it!” to the error message above. [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1) has got something on this, too, in case I’m too confusing…

But don’t let the naming of this alias restrict you ☺

Answer (score 1):

Nicest way I can do this is to make an autoloaded function, say `sudo_r`:

```
function sudo_r {
  typeset comm=$(hist -nl ${@:- -1 -1} | sed 1q);
  print -- $comm;
  sudo $comm;
}
```

Then (say) "alias ss=sudo_r".  When this is done, you can type `ss cp` to repeat the last command beginning with `cp`, but prefixing it with `sudo`.  Or if you
type `ss` <kbd>Return</kbd>, it will `sudo` the previous command.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to create an alias like this:

```
alias ss='sudo $(fc -r -l -n 1 1)
```

Example:

```
$ mkdir /test
mkdir: /test: Permission denied
$ ss
$ test -d /test && echo ok
ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I've used ksh but I believe the command was `recall` typically aliased to `r`

In bash you can recall the last command that began with any text
by entering the text and then `ESC CTRL-e`, this is advantageous over other ! style history commands as it simply 'recalls' the command without executing it, hence giving one a chance to edit the text before executing

```
$ sudu <ESC><CTRL>-e
```

recalls the last command that began with `sudo` onto the command line, to be edited before execution

Answer (score 0):

I use r #number to repeat a command from history. i.e.

```
dd762c1n4 /tmp 245$ history
245     history
dd762c1n4 /tmp 246$


dd762c1n4 /tmp 246$ r 245
history
245     history
246     history
dd762c1n4 /tmp 247$
```

Comment: Please add some details on what is that r and which package contains it. Your answer is not really helpful in this stage.